# Database Error - unsure what the issue is

Tags: database

this morning I started encountering database issues - the only thing I can think of is the upgrade to 5.9 that we did yesterday.

First discovery was the Cron error - via log.

```
    Jan 17 10:15:02  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => handle
        )

    [code] => -1
    [message] => DB Error: unknown error
    [mode] => 16
    [debug_info] => TRUNCATE TABLE civicrm_acl_contact_cache [nativecode=1932 ** Table 'tarabnyc_wordpress.civicrm_acl_contact_cache' doesn't exist in engine]
    [type] => DB_Error
    [user_info] => TRUNCATE TABLE civicrm_acl_contact_cache [nativecode=1932 ** Table 'tarabnyc_wordpress.civicrm_acl_contact_cache' doesn't exist in engine]
    [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: unknown error" code=-1 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info="TRUNCATE TABLE civicrm_acl_contact_cache [nativecode=1932 ** Table 'tarabnyc_wordpress.civicrm_acl_contact_cache' doesn't exist in engine]"]
)


    Jan 17 10:15:02  [info] $backTrace = #0 /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(232): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
    #1 /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(921): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))
    #2 /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB.php(985): PEAR_Error->__construct("DB Error: unknown error", -1, 16, (Array:2), "TRUNCATE TABLE civicrm_acl_contact_cache [nativecode=1932 ** Table 'tarabnyc_...")
    #3 /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(575): DB_Error->__construct(-1, 16, (Array:2), "TRUNCATE TABLE civicrm_acl_contact_cache [nativecode=1932 ** Table 'tarabnyc_...")
    #4 /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(223): PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -1, 16, (Array:2), "TRUNCATE TABLE civicrm_acl_contact_cache [nativecode=1932 ** Table 'tarabnyc_...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
    #5 /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1907): PEAR->__call("raiseError", (Array:7))
    #6 /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(933): DB_common->raiseError(-1, NULL, NULL, "TRUNCATE TABLE civicrm_acl_contact_cache [nativecode=1932 ** Table 'tarabnyc_...", "1932 ** Table 'tarabnyc_wordpress.civicrm_acl_contact_cache' doesn't exist in...")
    #7 /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(403): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()
    #8 /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery("TRUNCATE TABLE civicrm_acl_contact_cache")
    #9 /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2415): DB_common->query("TRUNCATE TABLE civicrm_acl_contact_cache")
    #10 /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1607): DB_DataObject->_query("TRUNCATE TABLE civicrm_acl_contact_cache")
    #11 /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(438): DB_DataObject->query("TRUNCATE TABLE civicrm_acl_contact_cache")
    #12 /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1490): CRM_Core_DAO->query("TRUNCATE TABLE civicrm_acl_contact_cache", TRUE)
    #13 /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/ACL/BAO/Cache.php(168): CRM_Core_DAO::singleValueQuery("TRUNCATE TABLE civicrm_acl_contact_cache")
    #14 /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Contact/Utils.php(926): CRM_ACL_BAO_Cache::resetCache()
    #15 /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cli.class.php(116): CRM_Contact_BAO_Contact_Utils::clearContactCaches()
    #16 /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cli.php(32): civicrm_cli->callApi()
    #17 {main}
```

Then the backtrace when trying to do anything.

```
pubic_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(190): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()
#1 /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(921): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))
#2 /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB.php(985): PEAR_Error->__construct("DB Error: unknown error", -1, 16, (Array:2), "TRUNCATE TABLE civicrm_acl_contact_cache [nativecode=1932 ** Table 'tarabnyc_...")
#3 /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(575): DB_Error->__construct(-1, 16, (Array:2), "TRUNCATE TABLE civicrm_acl_contact_cache [nativecode=1932 ** Table 'tarabnyc_...")
#4 /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(223): PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -1, 16, (Array:2), "TRUNCATE TABLE civicrm_acl_contact_cache [nativecode=1932 ** Table 'tarabnyc_...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#5 /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1907): PEAR->__call("raiseError", (Array:7))
#6 /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(933): DB_common->raiseError(-1, NULL, NULL, "TRUNCATE TABLE civicrm_acl_contact_cache [nativecode=1932 ** Table 'tarabnyc_...", "1932 ** Table 'tarabnyc_wordpress.civicrm_acl_contact_cache' doesn't exist in...")
#7 /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(403): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()
#8 /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery("TRUNCATE TABLE civicrm_acl_contact_cache")
#9 /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2415): DB_common->query("TRUNCATE TABLE civicrm_acl_contact_cache")
#10 /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1607): DB_DataObject->_query("TRUNCATE TABLE civicrm_acl_contact_cache")
#11 /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(438): DB_DataObject->query("TRUNCATE TABLE civicrm_acl_contact_cache")
#12 /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1413): CRM_Core_DAO->query("TRUNCATE TABLE civicrm_acl_contact_cache", TRUE)
#13 /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Config.php(362): CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery("TRUNCATE TABLE civicrm_acl_contact_cache")
#14 /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Form/Setting.php(145): CRM_Core_Config::clearDBCache()
#15 /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Form/Setting.php(103): CRM_Admin_Form_Setting->commonProcess((Array:0))
#16 /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(489): CRM_Admin_Form_Setting->postProcess()
#17 /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/StateMachine.php(160): CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()
#18 /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Next.php(61): CRM_Core_StateMachine->perform(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_Debugging), "next", "Next")
#19 /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Next->perform(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_Debugging), "next")
#20 /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_Debugging), "next")
#21 /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(351): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("next")
#22 /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Wrapper.php(113): CRM_Core_Controller->run()
#23 /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(282): CRM_Utils_Wrapper->run("CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_Debugging", "Debugging", (Array:0))
#24 /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:15))
#25 /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:4))
#26 /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1240): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:4))
#27 /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke("")
#28 /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters("", (Array:1))
#29 /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))
#30 /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php(224): do_action("toplevel_page_CiviCRM")
```

Lastly - when trying to upgrade from 5.9 to 5.9.1

```
Error: Finish Upgrade DB to 5.9.1]
Error Field Error Value
Type    DB_Error
Code    -1
Message DB Error: unknown error
Mode    16
UserInfo    TRUNCATE TABLE civicrm_acl_contact_cache [nativecode=1932 ** Table 'tarabnyc_wordpress.civicrm_acl_contact_cache' doesn't exist in engine]
DebugInfo   TRUNCATE TABLE civicrm_acl_contact_cache [nativecode=1932 ** Table 'tarabnyc_wordpress.civicrm_acl_contact_cache' doesn't exist in engine]
PEAR_Exception: DB Error: unknown error in /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php on line 921
- DB_Error: DB Error: unknown error in unknown on line unknown
Exception trace
#   Function    Location
0   CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler(Object(DB_Error))  /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php:921
1   PEAR_Error->__construct('DB Error: unknow…', -1, 16, Array, 'TRUNCATE TABLE c…')    /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB.php:985
2   DB_Error->__construct(-1, 16, Array, 'TRUNCATE TABLE c…')   /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php:575
3   PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), null, -1, 16, Array, 'TRUNCATE TABLE c…', 'DB_Error', true)    /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php:223
4   PEAR->__call('raiseError', Array)   /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php:1907
5   DB_common->raiseError(-1, null, null, 'TRUNCATE TABLE c…', '1932 ** Table 't…') /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php:933
6   DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()   /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php:403
7   DB_mysqli->simpleQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE c…') /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php:1216
8   DB_common->query('TRUNCATE TABLE c…')   /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php:2415
9   DB_DataObject->_query('TRUNCATE TABLE c…')  /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php:1607
10  DB_DataObject->query('TRUNCATE TABLE c…')   /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php:438
11  CRM_Core_DAO->query('TRUNCATE TABLE c…', true)  /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php:1490
12  CRM_Core_DAO::singleValueQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE c…') /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/ACL/BAO/Cache.php:168
13  CRM_ACL_BAO_Cache::resetCache() /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System.php:1448
14  CRM_Utils_System::flushCache()  /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Form.php:721
15  CRM_Upgrade_Form::doIncrementalUpgradeFinish(Object(CRM_Queue_TaskContext), '5.9.1', '5.9.0', '5.9.1', '/tmp/civicrm-pos…') /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Task.php:88
16  CRM_Queue_Task->run(Object(CRM_Queue_TaskContext))  /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Runner.php:214
17  CRM_Queue_Runner->runNext(true) /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Page/AJAX.php:52
18  CRM_Queue_Page_AJAX::{closure}()    /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Queue/ErrorPolicy.php:106
19  CRM_Queue_ErrorPolicy->call(Object(Closure))    /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Page/AJAX.php:54
20  CRM_Queue_Page_AJAX::runNext()  /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:275
21  CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem(Array) /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:84
22  CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke(Array) /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:52
23  CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke(Array)  /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php:1240
24  CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke('')   /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:286
25  WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)   /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:310
26  WP_Hook->do_action(Array)   /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php:453
    27  do_action('toplevel_page_Ci…')  /home5/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php:224
28  {main}
```

Comment: CiviCRM's reporting that some core tables are missing - would you check that you see the expected tables (MySQL: `SHOW TABLES`) in the expected database? Do you have WordPress and civicrm in the same DB? You might be able to restore that table from the pre upgrade backup, assuming one exists.

Comment: civicrm_acl_contact_cache seems to be the issue - it appears when I use `SHOW TABLES` but if I try to drop the table - i get the error - civicrm_acl_contact_cache doesn't exist in engine.

Comment: I can't comment on the second part of this - but the first error IS fixed by upgrading to 5.9.1.

Comment: I have seen issues where the table was visible in `SHOW TABLES` but not accessible as a table with data - roughly described in [this SE Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10622738/43034). Bad times - you may be looking at a full DB restore, and possibly even a full restore of ibdata 

Comment: Try [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25720558/43034) before you go too far! It may work out for you. A good time to check your backups & underlying systems (eg, are those disks healthy?).

Comment: Thank you so much @ChrisBurgess - that helped! and yes - its a very important time to check backups and underlying systems - Provide an answer - I will select it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As established from the comments on your original question, this appears to have been a corrupted MySQL table.

CiviCRM was reporting in the backtrace that a core table did not exist:

> TRUNCATE TABLE civicrm_acl_contact_cache [nativecode=1932 ** **Table 'example.civicrm_acl_contact_cache' doesn't exist in engine**]

You used MySQL to inspect the DB using `SHOW TABLES` (or `SHOW TABLES LIKE 'name_of_missing_table'`). MySQL reported the table was present. However, when you tried to drop the table, MySQL reported that the table was missing.

Since the table is a cache table which CiviCRM can regenerate from other data in the DB, it was possible to replace the corrupted table's disk files. The [workaround I believe you used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25720558/43034) requires direct access to the files in the MySQL server's data directory - not an option for all sites.

Comment: These tables are write intensive and (aside from CiviCRM's `log_*` tables) in my experience are the most likely to fail due to disk corruption, have issues with deadlocks etc. If you feel bold enough, it might be good to investigate [moving them to MEMORY storage](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html), which should reduce disk writes / risk of disk corruption, and probably reduce the chances of deadlocks along the way. **I haven't tried this myself**.

Answer (score 0):

Something has deleted your ibdata1 file where InnoDB keeps the dictionary. Definitely it's not MySQL who does it.

Cheers

Pradeep

Comment: Can you update your answer to show how you determined that Pradeep? It seems odd to me that CiviCRM / WordPress had got that far in the boot process if the entire DB has been removed, so I'm wondering what clue you're seeing and I'm missing!

Answer (score 0):

**My solution is very noob, but it works:** 
**1) backup the database first with myphpadmin, it will skip civicrm_acl_contact_cache since its corrupted

2) drop and restore the current db, use old civicrm database sql backup** (if you don't have you can also create new civicrm and make new db backup)**, open the sql file with notepad** (I would use notepad++ or open sql workbench) **find civicrm_acl_contact_cache** 

**3) copy paste and run all civicrm_acl_contact_cache SQL code in the SQL query box and there you go**